# Is there a method of checking if there is a certain object's set in another?

Tags: python

I want to test if the first number in the one of my sets is also the same as a number in either of two different sets, then do the same for the second, third, etc. If it the first number is the same as the player's set's first number I want to have the player be able to do an action, but if it is the enemy's set's then I want them to go. Is there a way to accomplish that?

```
Pm1 = input("What is your knight's name?")
Pm2 = input("What is your theif's name?")
Pm3 = input("What is your doctor's name?")
Pm4 = input("What is your priest's name?")
import random
Pm1Order = random.randint(1,8) 
Pm2Order = random.randint(1,8)
if Pm2Order == Pm1Order: 
    Pm2Order = Pm1Order - 1
    if Pm2Order == 0:
        Pm2Order = Pm1Order + 1
Pm3Order = random.randint(1,8) 
if Pm3Order == Pm2Order:
    Pm3Order = Pm1Order - 2
    if Pm3Order == 0:
        Pm3Order = Pm1Order + 2
Pm4Order = random.randint(1,8)
if Pm4Order == Pm3Order:
    Pm4Order = Pm1Order - 3
    if Pm4Order == 0:
        Pm4Order = Pm1Order + 3
print("The turn orders for your party is " +str(Pm1Order)+ " for the knight, " +str(Pm2Order)+ " for the theif, " +str(Pm3Order)+ " for the doctor, and " +str(Pm4Order)+ " for the priest.")
PlayerOrder = set([Pm1Order , Pm2Order , Pm3Order , Pm4Order])
print(str(PlayerOrder))
FullOrder = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
EnemyOrder = FullOrder.difference(PlayerOrder)
EnemyOrder2 = FullOrder.difference(PlayerOrder)
print(str(EnemyOrder))
Enemy1Order = random.sample(EnemyOrder, 1)
Enemy2Order = random.sample(EnemyOrder, 1)
Enemy3Order = random.sample(EnemyOrder, 1)
Enemy4Order = random.sample(EnemyOrder, 1)
print(Enemy1Order)
AllOrder = set([Pm1Order, Pm2Order, Pm3Order, Pm4Order, Enemy1Order, Enemy2Order, Enemy3Order, Enemy4Order])
AllOrder.sort(key = int)
print(AllOrder)
####Test for first element if its player then they go if its enemey they go and
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your question wrong, but you refer to the "first number in [a] set".  One of the important things to realize about `set`s is that they do not have any internal order. Also, it's a little unclear what you're looking for.  Could you reduce your code a little to just the parts that really matter to the problem you're having?

Comment: What I mean is that I want the set to organize in numerical order, then test if the first element in the set is an element within the Player set or the Enemy set. The part of the code I'm concerned with is the line that has PlayerOrder = set([Pm1Order , Pm2Order , Pm3Order , Pm4Order])

Comment: For consistency, maybe misspell "preist", too? (-8

Answer (score 0):

Use `min` instead of `set.sort`.  Because `set`s don't have any internal ordering, you can't sort them in place.  You could use `sorted(your_set)`, but if all you care about is the smallest element, that's all you need to get.

```
first_turn = min(AllOrder)

if first_turn in EnemyOrder:
    ...
elif first_turn in PlayerOrder:
    ...
```